# Correct Alphabetical Order - platform-wide solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Currently in our app we do not override the system’s default method for alphabetizing data, it will sort capital letters over lowercase letters.

How to enable case-insensitive across the application without changing the collation?

Database: PostgreSQL

Any idea on this ?

Comment: Why don't you want to change your DB's text columns' collation when you already noticed that the current collation doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: @spickermann - I don't want to touch the collation part. Is there any other way to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand your request -- you'd like to change the collation, without changing the collation? The only other option would be to change the SQL statements, but doing that "globally" isn't really possible - you'd need to do it somewhere in your Rails models.

Comment: @TomLord - Without changing the collation. Is there any other options?

Comment: Like I wrote above: By (one way or another) changing the SQL statements. For example, adding scopes such as `scope :order_by_name, -> { order('LOWER(name)') }`.

Comment: @VDN would you mind to explain why changing the collation isn't an option?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but feel free to check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html Most likely you have to change your SQL statements and indexes. Yes, also the indexes, or all current indexes on text columns will be useless.

Comment: @Stefan - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275533/is-it-possible-to-change-collation-for-an-existing-database-with-postgresql

Comment: @TomLord - If I have 100 models we need to write a scope :order_by_name, -> { order('LOWER(name)') } in all 100 models right which is not good instead of that we can have a common config kind of code that would be better. Please let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks!

Comment: @VDN quoting the answer: _"`pg_dump` the database, create a new database with the desired collation and restore the dump into the new database."_

Comment: @Stefan - Is it possible to change collation for an existing database with PostgreSQL?

The reason is that there may be data structures in the database that depend on the database's collation: indexes over string data types. If you'd be able to change the collation on the fly, all these indexes would implicitly become corrupted.

Comment: @VDN hence the suggestion to dump the database and create a new one with the collation you want.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty work-around could be adding a scope like this to your `ApplicationRecord`:

```
scope :order_ci, ->(attribute) { order("LOWER(#{attribute})") }
```

Or like this using a specific collate:

```
scope :order_ci, ->(attribute) { order("#{attribute} COLLATE en_US.UTF-8") }
```

And then use that scope like this `Foo.order_ci(:name)` instead of `Foo.order(:name)`.

But keep in mind that this “solution” has many flaws: The `order` method that comes with Ruby on Rails accepts many data types and formats (single values, hashes, strings, lists) and not only one but many attributes at the same time. And the Rails method sanitized the input correctly, this method does not.

Which means, when you want to use such a work-around instead of fixing your database's collation. Then you need to make sure that your overridden method is able to basically handle all data formats and does proper sanitization as the Ruby on Rails method would do. Otherwise, you risk bugs in the best case and security vulnerabilities in the worst case.